# WordPress index page is returning 404 and admin page requires /index.php in url

Tags: url-rewriting, installation

My WordPress installation is in a different folder from my main site:

`/var/www/html/wordpress` <= WP installation

`/var/www/html/main-site` <= main site

I would like to have WP display when someone visits /blog from my main site:

http://www.main-site.com/blog (Note: main-site is used as a generic placeholder for the real site because it is not launched yet)

I have set up an alias in my httpd conf file:

```
Alias /blog /var/www/html/wordpress 
<Directory /var/www/html/main-site>
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    Options -MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    order allow,deny
    allow from all 
</Directory>
```

I have the following as my .htaccess file for WP:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I get a 404 when I visit http://www.main-site.com/blog but when I visit http://www.main-site.com/wp-admin/index.php, it works (but I get a 404 if I visit /admin). Visiting the sample blog post and sample page also works for me.

http://www.main-site.com/blog/hello-world/

http://www.main-site.com/blog/sample-page/

It looks like rewrite is working but my /blog index page doesn't work.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Allen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured this one out! It turns out that Passenger was enabled.

```
Alias /blog /var/www/html/wordpress 
<Directory /var/www/html/main-site>
    PassengerEnabled off
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    Options -MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    order allow,deny
    allow from all 
</Directory>
```